# Excel 2013: Using an Indirect in an If statement's clause for a data validation list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a data validation drop down list containing available router interfaces (column E) based off the router 1's model (column B) and router 2's model (column C).

I have working a list of interfaces (column D) for router1 using:

```
=INDIRECT("TBL_Device_Interfaces[" & INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) & "]")
```

This is where I run into an issue. For Col E, I need to do the same indirect for the table list but, if current rows's COL C = "not used" then used COL B's value, else use COL C's value.

I first tried this but it did not work:

```
=INDIRECT("TBL_Device_Interfaces[" & INDIRECT(IF(INDIRECT("C" & ROW()) = "not used", "B", "C") * ROW()) & "]")
```

Then I tried, but it did not work:

```
=If(INDIRECT("C" & ROW()) = "not used", INDIRECT("TBL_Device_Interfaces[" & INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) & "]"), INDIRECT("TBL_Device_Interfaces[" & INDIRECT("C" & ROW()) & "]"))
```

But this is what is killing me. Because this works... but I need static columns but dynamic rows based off current row:

```
=If($C$6 = "not used", INDIRECT("TBL_Device_Interfaces[" & INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) & "]"), INDIRECT("TBL_Device_Interfaces[" & INDIRECT("C" & ROW()) & "]"))
```

NOTE: I typed this by hand off an offline PC. Sorry if there are any type-os (like spelling indirect wrong). Those would not be in the main code. I have if all working in segments but I cannot get it to work in data validation.

I am also up to is there is another way to create a drop down list. I just need to be able to reference values tables using index/match and indirects.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing different cell reference styles. If you think about how your formula will execute its saying "Go check out TBL_Device_Interfaces[B3]". You can see how to build [structured table references here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) You either need to stick with a structured table reference or switch back to a standard reference.

Try your formula as:

```
=IF($C$6 = "not used", INDIRECT( INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) ), INDIRECT(INDIRECT("C" & ROW()) ))
```

or if you want to stick with the structured reference try:

```
=IF(TBL_Device_Interfaces[@Column3] = "not used", TBL_Device_Interfaces[@Column2], TBL_Device_Interfaces[@Column1])
```

I may have your columns wrong, but it should work.

Comment: Column B = Router 1, Column C = Router 2, Column D = Interface 1, Column E = Interface 2. There are always two interfaces. I need the data val list to reflect the interfaces form the table based off the model type select in COL C ... unless there is no second router in which it will pull the interface list of the model type in COL B.

Comment: For example: Cisco interfaces = Gi, Te. Juniper interface = ge, xe. COL B ROW()= Cisco, COL C ROW()= Juniper. I want the dropdown list of COL E to be ge or xe. But if COL E = Cisco I want it to be Gi or Te. Like I said this is an example, the list if more extensive and contains many model types. Also the reason I do not define the exact cell and using an indirect in the if function is because this is a service being build per row. So I need to use the same drop down list for 100 rows and dont want to continue to edit individual rows. I need a dynamic solution based off the choice n the cur row

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning the data in COL B and C are the table's header values for the interfaces. Which is why I am using table references.

Comment: Can you upload a simplified example?

Comment: Figured it out, sorry. You can't  use Row() in data validation list.